# Python. Django - How to call a python function when submitting form with Ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have an error when loading the app which says that url in form's *action* attribute is not correct. I've googled for several hours and tried different variants, still no result.
I'm totally new to django and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

This is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from form import UserForm

def index(request):
    text = "Welcome"
    template = loader.get_template('myapp/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'text': text,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))


def get_data(request):
    if request.POST:
       form = UserForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          login = form.cleaned_data['login']
          password = form.cleaned_data['password']

     return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {
               'login': login,
               'password': password, })
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from myapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$/login/$', views.get_data, name='get_data'),
)
```

index.html:

```
<h1>{{ text }}</h1>

<form action="{% url get_data %}" method="post" id="auth">
{% csrf_token %}
    <p>Login:<br>
    <input type="text" name="login" id="login"> </p>

    <p>Password:<br>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password"> </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in"">      
</form>

<div id="check"></div>
<div>{{login}}</br>
     {{password}}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#auth');

    frm.submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serializeArray(),
            cache: false, 
            success: function (data) {
                $("#check").html(data); 
            },
            error: function(data) {
                $("#check").html("Something went wrong!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action attribute of the form should be action="{% url 'get_data' %}", not action="{% url get_data %}".